# Android ListView layout param set

Tags: android, listview, layout, layoutparams

I have a Listview in my xml. The structure of it like that:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/SeriesCastListItemView"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"/>
```

Now I want to set a height for the `Listview` by java code. i am tried with following code.

```
ListView castListItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SeriesCastListItemView);
castListItemView.setAdapter(new CastAdapter(this, castDescriptionArr));
castListItemView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500));
```

But it giving `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams`. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the LayoutParams of the parent view that contains your ListView.  In my case, I placed the ListView in a Frame Layout, and used this code.  If you placed the ListView in a LinearLayout you would use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

```
ListView castListItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SeriesCastListItemView);
castListItemView.setAdapter(new CastAdapter(this, castDescriptionArr));
castListItemView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500));
```

I assume it was a typo in your question, but make sure that the "c" in castListItemView is lowercase on your third line.

MrJre brings up a good point though.  Because many different views have their own LayoutParams, it is best to include the view whose parameters you wish to use (as in FrameLayout.LayoutParams) instead of making Eclipse guess based on which LayoutParams class you previously imported.

You can see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631966/set-relativelayout-layout-params-programmatically-throws-classcastexception) for more information.

Comment: The LayoutParamss works. But castListItemView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500)) this overwrites any thing that is on the top of the layout. Even though the listview is below the image which is on the top, the listview contents are placed on the image. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Ashwin I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you post a separate question with your code?

Answer (score 0):

in this line:`new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500)` you are mixing up LayoutParams classes.

Either

```
new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500)
```

or

```
new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 500)
```

will fix it is my guess.

Comment: CastListItemView.setLayoutParams() or castListItemView.setLayoutParams() ?