# Unable to set margin of item in ListView using custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am attempting to set variable left margins for items in my ListView. The problem occurs in my custom Adapter in the getView method:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            Comment c = comments.get(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);               
            (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.story)).setText(c.message);


        }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(0, c.getDepth() * 5, 0, 0);               
            convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return convertView;
    }
```

We inflate the list_item layout which is a RelativeLayout with some textViews inside. I then attempt to set the margins using a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.  I get a class cast exception on this, but the normal LayoutParams type has no method for setting the margins.

What is the best way to go about setting the margin?

Here is the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1779)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1748)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1145)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the simplest way to solve this problem was to  simply wrap my item in a FrameLayout in the xml. I could then easily set the left padding as I wished thus giving me the exact look I was hoping for.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure where you have your ClassCast exception, is it on `convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);` ? If yes, then supply your `list_item` xml file please. As your layout is a `RelativeLayout`, then you have to supply a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, as you did.

**EDIT**: Due to the `ListView`, the same `LayoutParams` as parent has to be supplied, a `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. However, this kind of layout doesn't provide the `margin` setter. On other stackoverflow thread, I saw that you have to inflate the layout like this: `inflate(xml_id, listView, false);` to explicitely said there is no connection with the `ListView` and the content. However, I couldn't make it working either.

Plus, I see you're setting the margin in the `convertView` creation. If you do like this, then only the items which are firstly created will have their own custom margin. Other will have the recycled view margin. I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: It actually seems to occur after I return the converView, though you are correct that I need to set the margin earlier. I added the error to my post.

Comment: I made a simple app to test it, but didn't manage to make it working. I suggest you use View padding instead, which has I think the same behaviour. convertView.setPadding(0, c.getDepth() * 5, 0, 0); Sorry to don't bring more help :/

Comment: Unfortunately I actually want the entire view to be shifted over, and padding only creates a space within the view. Thanks for trying!