# android class cast excp relative layout

Tags: android

i am getting class cast exception relative$layout here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Delete" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button2" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Edit" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button2"></Button>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

.

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class options extends ExpandableListActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);               
    }

    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
                { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
                { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
                { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
        };
        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }
        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }
        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }
        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            //AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            //        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

            //TextView textView = new TextView(options.this);
           // textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
           // textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            //textView.setPadding(60, 0, 0, 0);

            //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            //return textView;

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)options.this.getSystemService
                      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            return textView;

        }

    }
}
```

in the last getGenericView() code in comment works fine but i am trying to inflate from row.xml which gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inflate row into a View.  At least go up to ViewGroup.  View doesn't have children, so the implementation of findViewById can't search for child views

This should work:

```
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: nope not working :( threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1068)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1149)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271):at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
and so on a long list of similar error

Comment: This seems to be happening inside the ListView's code.  Copy the whole thing into your question in a code block so we can see the last bit of user code (notice that all of the methods and lines of code in the top of the stack trace is actually code executing in the Android framework).

Comment: Btw, check this one out...looks similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631966/set-relativelayout-layout-params-programmatically-throws-classcastexception