# Change relativelayout height

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

I got this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams`

I think the error is caused by the fact that i have a relative layout in a linear layout
I looked for same problems:[Set RelativeLayout layout params programmatically - throws ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631966/set-relativelayout-layout-params-programmatically-throws-classcastexception)

But this didn't help

My code :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsT1score = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mT1layoutScore.getLayoutParams();
                // Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
                paramsT1score.height = 80;
                mT1layout.setLayoutParams(paramsT1score);
```

This is my .xml

```
</RelativeLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#314ebd"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutT1score"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/LayoutT2score">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team 1"
            android:id="@+id/lblTeam1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/player1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/player1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/player1"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutT2score"
        android:background="#fbff62"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team 2"
            android:id="@+id/lblTeam2"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/player2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/player2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/player2" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout params type is determined by the parent type. You get the layout params from one view `mT1layoutScore` and then try to set up them in another `mT2layout` the parent of which is of a different type.

Set the layout params on the same object, or since you're editing the layout params in-place, just call `mT1layoutScore.requestLayout()`.

Comment: could you give me a extensive example?

Comment: Replace the `mT2layout.setLayoutParams()` with `mT1layoutScore.requestLayout()`.

Comment: THanks, A classic example of copying gone wrong. I think i need some more sleep

Answer (score 0):

Hm, seems like params of mT1layoutScore is `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but params of mT2layout is `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

So, i think you should create

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsT2score = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mT2layout.getLayoutParams();
```

then copy all needed params from paramsT1score to paramsT2score, and then added

```
mT2layout.setLayoutParams(paramsT2score);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error:  android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: in the link is mentioned that you need to use te parent type of layout See link: Set RelativeLayout layout params programmatically - throws ClassCastException

Comment: @matthijsW hm, now I remember... I had the same error after changing my layout. Try to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I made some mistakes stupid mistakes in my code but thanks for the help. Learned something

Comment: @matthijsW nice to hear that you found mistake )